Multiplicative Alpha Blend mode
Blender used to have an "additive" and "multiplicative" alpha blend mode in the ~2.79ish days before it was removed in favor of a simpler setup. The additive blend mode is still easily replicable with an "Add Shader" node, but I'm not sure how or even if it's possible to recreate the multiply blend mode in modern versions.
A comment on the original issue for the change seems to imply that it is/was possible to recreate both setups, but I don't know how accurate that is now.
